# Posting a Mongoose Nested Schema to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to post a nested schema to my MongoDB.
my mongoose schema looks like this:

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  code: String,
  leader: String,
  member1: {
    no: Number,
    name: String,
    desc: String,
    target: Number,
  },
  member2: {
    no: Number,
    name: String,
    desc: String,
    target: Number,
  }
}
const Project = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);
```

and i want to make a POST req to mongoDB with this:

```
app.post("/api/postproject", (req, res) => {
  const project = new Project({
    title: req.body.title,
    code: req.body.code,
    leader: req.body.leader,
    member1: {
      no: req.body.member1.no,
      name: req.body.member1.name,
      desc: req.body.member1.desc,
      target: req.body.member1.target
    },
    member2: {
      no: req.body.member2.no,
      name: req.body.member2.name,
      desc: req.body.member2.desc,
      target: req.body.member2.target
    }
  })
})
```

anyone spot the error here?
I tried but the nested object didn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a member locally first and then pass it as an entire object:

```
app.post("/api/postproject", (req, res) => {
  let member1 = {
    no: req.body.member1.no,
    name: req.body.member1.name,
    desc: req.body.member1.desc,
    target: req.body.member1.target
  }
  let member2 = {
    no: req.body.member2.no,
    name: req.body.member2.name,
    desc: req.body.member2.desc,
    target: req.body.member2.target
  }
  const project = new Project({
    title: req.body.title,
    code: req.body.code,
    leader: req.body.leader,
    member1: member1,
    member2: member2
  })
})
```

Alternatively, you could create such object on the front-end before making the request and then just use `req.body.member1` right away.